# Is it possible to loop a list of videos?

Tags: html, video, loops

The title pretty much says it all. I have a spot on a webpage that currently plays a video. I'd like to update the page such that I can add a line of code with a reference to a couple files located in a folder with the source, and the page will play the first video, then the second, etc. until it reaches the final video, and then play the first video again, looping indefinitely. It's extremely preferable that this line of code would be able to play video files, .swf files, pictures (for a pre-determined length of time), etc.

Currently, I'm just using a very rudimentary

```
<video width="100%" height="100%">
        <embed loop="true" showcontrols="0" align="left" src="New Site Folder\DemoVid_sound_mods.avi"/>
</video>
```

The problem with this, though, is that it only plays one video, and if I want to add more parts to it, I have to edit the video itself, rather than just popping a new file in the folder.

I saw another question answered that mentioned doing this with javascript, but the whole point of this project is to make it exceptionally easy and quick to update. The main thing I'm looking for here is for us to be able to update the page by opening a file in notepad, adding a line of code, saving, and running it.

Any thoughts? Even just a pointer on what commands might be useful here would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you won't be able to do this with the inbuilt html5 video players native to the browser, It's just not the principle on which they are built.

What you are looking for is more of a media playlist style set of features.

You will have to use one of the javascript based html5 video players to get some of these features but even then I'm not sure of the support for swf and image files I've seen a few which do various videos and audio files but nothing HTML5 which also does swfs also as again, the premise of these players is usually to eradicate flash.

My best suggestion for doing all of these in one single embed is to use flash via the longtail/jw player or flowplayer which handles playlists etc or perhaps slideshowpro which I know does both images, video and I think audio too.

Finally.. harking back a decade or so. theres a Language which is pretty underused and suffers varied support called SMIL which supports all of these elements you mentioned however it's uptake sort of fell apart with the introduction of video in flash. I remember that Realplayer and Quicktime could serve SMIL files but I'd be pretty cautious to do anything in SMIL these days.

Hope that helps.
A

Comment: Awesome. I'll check that SMIL thing out. Sucks HTML doesn't have better support for this considering how widespread video use is on the interbutts.